# Is it possible to build a dynamic chainable scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, scope

Suppose I have these three models

```
class Plant < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pots
  has_many :fertilizers
end

class Pot < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plant
end

class Fertilizer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :plant
end
```

Each one has an attribute of `grouped_by`.

Is it possible to make a `grouped_as` scope that can be applied at the end of of either :

```
@plant.pots.grouped_as('outdoors')
@plants.fertilizers.grouped_as('outdoors')
```

So that I could add `grouped_as` as a chainable scope to any relation, and it would automagically look for a common attribute between the `Plant` and its dynamic children, `pots` or `fertilizers`..

Or would I have to just make a custom scope for each one?

Comment: Do you want a scope on Plant that return either Fertilizer and/or Pot records based on their `grouped_by` attribute?

Comment: I think I just figured it out. It is with common named association extensions. I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0):

From http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

The idea is to use Association Extensions and then separate them to shared modules.

```
module FindOrCreateByNameExtension
  def find_or_create_by_name(name)
    first_name, last_name = name.split(" ", 2)
    find_or_create_by(first_name: first_name, last_name: last_name)
  end
end

class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people, extend: FindOrCreateByNameExtension
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people, extend: FindOrCreateByNameExtension
end
```

Comment: FWIW, a slightly more concise syntax: `has_many :people, extend: FindOrCreateByNameExtension`